# What does mean % , $_ and @ in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

What does this mean: `$_` and `%` in Powershell?

```
1..10 | Foreach {if($_%2){"$_ is odd number"}}
```

Comment: While @AdminOfThings has provided you with a good answer, you could have easily found the answers yourself with just a little bit of research.

Comment: I agree, this seem like something that could easily be answered as the result of a quick google search. Did you try that?

Answer (score 20):

- `%`

  - In your case, it is the modulus operator. It will return the remainder of dividing the left-hand side value by the right-hand side value.
  - It defaults as a PowerShell alias for `Foreach-Object`. You can execute the `Get-Alias` command to see other potential aliases that may contain special characters like `Where-Object`'s alias `?`.

---

- `$_`

  - Synonymous with `$PSItem`
  - Contains the current object in the pipeline object
  - In your case, it represents the current object passed into your `Foreach-Object` script block (`{}`).
  - It will commonly show up in the `Where-Object {}` script block and `Select-Object` hash tables.

---

- `@`

  - A literal `@` character
  - Denotes splatting

    - The syntax is `@VariableName`. The variable can be an array or hash table. It is commonly used with a hash table or dictionary where the Name property represents a parameter name and the value property is the value for that parameter. Then that variable is splatted into another command. An example is `Get-Process @Params`.
  - Used for declaring and initializing arrays via the array sub-expression operator `@()`.

    - Examples are `$myArray = @()` and `$myArray = @("value1","value2")`.
  - Used to create and/or initialize a hash table

    - The syntax is `$variable = @{}` or `$variable = @{Property=Value}`.
  - Used in here-strings

    - Here-strings are special case strings that can expand multiple lines and contain special characters
    - Denoted by beginning a string value with `@'` or `@"` and closing the string value with a corresponding `'@` or `"@`.

      - The here-string open and close characters should be isolated on their respective lines of the right-hand side (RHS).
  - Common At symbol

    - Used in email address construction, i.e. user@domain.com.
    - Used in external program remote logon syntax, i.e. user@hostname.

---

**Extra Reading and Notable Links:**

1. See [About Arithmetic Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6) for information on modulus among other arithmetic operators.
2. See [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6) for more information about `Foreach-Object` and how objects are processed.
3. See [About Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) for more information and usage of splatting.
4. Another good resource is [About Automatic Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6), which will list PowerShell's reserved/automatic variables. They are created and maintained by PowerShell. You will notice there are some variables that have non-alpha and non-numeric characters. You should only use these variables for their intended purposes and not use their names when you create your own custom variables.
5. See [About Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6) for details on the array sub-expression operator.
6. See [About Hash Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) for details on creating and manipulating hash table objects.
7. See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) to see more information and examples of using here-strings.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that `%` is also an alias for `ForEach-Object`. That is not how it is being used in the example, but it *can* be used as such.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I have added that. Thank you

Comment: And what about `@` (_Commercial At_) in other context(s) than splatting like `@{…}` (_create a hash table_), `@(…)`  (_array sub-expression operator_) or creating a here-string (see _about_Quoting_Rules_). Did I miss some?

Comment: @JosefZ, I updated to add array sub-expression, hash table, and here-string syntax. Now that the post is growing, I need to reformat it

Comment: Amazing effort… 